# What is the difference between @latest and @upgrade special queries in golang?

Tags: go

What is the difference between `@latest` and `@upgrade` special queries when working with golang module commands, for example `go get`?

I thought `latest` would just set the selected module to the latest known version, and `upgrade` would just "upgrade" to the next known version (if none is known, then it will download the last one). However, in both cases it only goes to the latest version, so what is the difference?

Comment: Maybe the next known version is also the latest? How did you check and got that result?

Comment: @MilosStojanovic You can check by using this module (github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter). It has 3 version, so its easy to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting and paraphrasing the documentation (https://go.dev/ref/mod#version-queries)

> "latest" which selects the highest available release version. If there are no release versions, latest selects the highest pre-release version. If there are no tagged versions, latest selects a pseudo-version for the commit at the tip of the repository’s default branch.

> "upgrade" which is like "latest" except that if the module is currently required at a higher version than the version latest would select (for example, a pre-release), upgrade will select the current version.

> For example, if versions v1.2.2 and v1.2.3-pre are available, the latest query will select v1.2.2, even though v1.2.3-pre is higher.

Comment: Thanks, can you just link the documentation where you found it :)